# Long Text Area Field check for null

Tags: apex, visualforce

What is the correct way to check if a long text area field is null/empty? Does a simple != null suffice?

```
if (numberApprove>0 && insuranceRecord.Comments_Private__c != null){
    sMessage = sMessage + 'Include information in the Comments field about approvals';
}
```

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: This is Apex code that checks whether the comment section in an insurance record has been populated. If the comment section has not been populated then they will receive a dialog box with the message "Include information in the Comments field about approvals".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long text area value is still a string so you can use standard string functions. Try this:

```
if (numberApprove>0 && String.isBlank(insuranceRecord.Comments_Private__c)){
    sMessage = sMessage + 'Include information in the Comments field about approvals';
}
```

If you want to check whether it is not blank, then use `String.isNotBlank(insuranceRecord.Comments_Private__c)`

Comment: That works lovely, thanks